# sharepoint 2013 server public facing site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement to create a public facing site in sharepoint 2013 server and admin can login and add,update and delete.

How to implement this?

Any suggestions would be appreicated

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: how to implement this?

Comment: http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/building-public-facing-websites-on-sharepoint-2013-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having only one server and want pure anonymous.

First, install sharepoint to a port other that 80,443, for example 999.  Then, you extend the web application (as public site) to port 80.
In that way, as an administrator, you can loggin to port 999 and do CRUD operations. If you have a firewall, you can stop port 80 to connect to the internet.